# Mongodb storing JSON file in binary form

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to Mongodb and Backend Development. I have a created a system where a user can create a json. I'm storing the json in the data base but when I retrieve the data is appearing as Binary Data. How do I convert this to JSON. There is no converter online, I have google extensively. Thanks.

This is what I'm getting back.

{ _bsontype: 'Binary',
  sub_type: 0,
  position: 1269,
  buffer:  }

This is the Model

```
   // app/models/project.js
  // load the things we need 
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

 // define the schema for our project model
     var projectSchema = mongoose.Schema({


             id        : String,
             allwork :[ 
                      {

                                      protocol     : String,
                                     name         : String,
                                     json         : Object
                    }
                   ]



  });



  // create the model for users and expose it to our app

  module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema);
```

This is the Query

```
  var Project = require('./app/models/project');
   Project.findOne({ 'id' : 'pop'  }, function(err, callback) {
    if (err) return "Error searching person";
    if(callback) {
      console.log(callback.allwork);
      for(var i = 0; i < callback.allwork.length; i++) {
           if(callback.allwork[i].name == "zingzong"){

          console.log(callback.allwork[i].json);

       }
  }
//socket.emit('callback_allwork', callback.allwork);
    }
    });
  });
```

This logs the buffer with binary data instead of the json that i originaly saved.

This is the function to save the json

```
                        callback.allwork.push({
                protocol : a.user.project.protocol,
                name : a.user.project.name,
                json : a.user.project.json
            })

                callback.save(function (err) {
                if(!err) {
                    global.mess = "Project save succesfully"    ;   
                    return;
                    }

                        });
```

Comment: This is what the buffer looks like  0a 7b 0a 20 20 20 20 22 6e 61 6d 65 22 3a 20 22 66 6c 61 72 65 22 2c 0a 20 20 20 20 22 63 68 69 6c 64 72 65 6e 22 3a 20 5b 7b 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ... > }

Comment: Show us some code, how do you store and retrieve the data

Comment: Show your code, your intention is to store the JSON input as textual data?

Comment: No I want to store a json file as a json and then retrieve the json at request.

Comment: In the schema the json file is stored in the "json" key.

Comment: `a.user.project.json` must be a buffer so it's stored as binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `json: Object` to `json: String`. String will give you what you want, which is text, not binary. Refer to [this page](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) to see more about Mongoose schema types.

If you want a structured option, not just a text field, consider using `Schema.Types.Mixed`. As I don't know how you will manipulate this in the database, I cannot tell you whether `String` or `Schema.Types.Mixed` is best suited for you. I'd stick to `String`, however.

Comment: I'm still getting the data back in binary. Mongodb converts document to BSON. It doesn't make a difference if its string or json.

Comment: @Batman please add to your question the part of the program where the document is saved.